# How to filter data on request in laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, ajax, laravel

I've in my React component this function:

```
const url = '/category';


function hideOnClick(id) {
  setHide({value: id})
  console.log(id);
  const body = {
      'chordId' : id,
  }

  const requestMetadata = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    console.log(body);

  fetch(url, requestMetadata)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            url: res
        })
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

In my route/web this line:

```
Route::post('/category', [PostController::class, 'postBody']);
```

And finally in my PostController this function

```
public function postBody(Request $request)
{
    $chord = $request->get('chordId');

    $posts = Post::join('categories', function ($builder) {
        $builder->on('categories.id', '=', 'posts.category_id');
    })
    ->where('name', '=', Str::before($chord, '.'))
    ->get();


    return view("posts.index-category")->with(array("posts" => $posts));
}
```

I have this graph dynamically rendered with categories and I want to make it interactive and used to filter posts based on where the user click on the graph.

Right now in my network tab I'm able to see the fetch request with a status of 200, and in the preview I see my view index-category with the correct posts, based on the filter in my PostController.

But I don't know how to show this result in my page without a full page refresh. I think I've to use something like ajax but I don't know how. Someone has any suggest?

Comment: you said it, you shoud ajax, there is gooe library for that called Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios), 
something else. you should not return the entire view, only the data, 
and then you would change the view from react to display the fetched data

Comment: I've to change all the logic in my fuction "HideonClick" to use axios, or I can just add it in some way?

Comment: you don't need to do anything, you can just return the data in JSON instead of view, 
and then display with react `return ["posts" => $posts];`

Comment: which charting library are you using ?